# URL validation with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible with ServiceStack to detect URL parameters that ServiceStack could not map into your DTO and fail as a result? Something like an event you could hook would be useful if you wanted to guarantee failure on invalid data.

For example, say you requested

```
http://www.mydomain.com/GlobalCustomers?Name=Smith&Location=East
```

Now say the GlobalCustomers service doesn't support this form of querying by Location; maybe some more primitive (say North America-specific) service did, and somebody assumed the same query would work here. Perhaps the GlobalCustomers service instead supports querying by time zone:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/GlobalCustomers?Name=Smith&TimeZone=UTC-5
```

Rather than ignore the incorrect Location parameter in the first URL, let's say your uniform contract requires you to fail outright in the presence of a bad request like that one. What's the easiest way to guarantee such failure, both as globally as possible and specific to individual services (in case some services want to look directly at the request to pull out unspecified parameters)?